# Local variables not working in a gnu Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am running `make` on `macOS` and it is not pleased with any local variables . Take this snippet intended to get the full path to the directory of the Makefile script

```
setup_for_run:
    mkfile_path=$(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
    mkfile_dir=$(dir $(mkfile_path))
    echo "scriptdir=$(SCRIPT_DIR)"
    export PATH=$($(SCRIPT_DIR)/.venv/bin:$(PATH))
```

The result of `make setup_for_run` is:

```
$make setup_for_run
mkfile_path=/Users/steve/git/hercl/Makefile
mkfile_dir=
echo "scriptdir="
scriptdir=
export PATH=
```

So we see that none of the local variables are operational.  What is the way to get them activated in the `gnu make` installed by default on `macOS` ?

Comment: `make` creates a new shell for each recipe line, at least by default. So not only are variables destroyed at the end of line, the effects of `export PATH` also don't last.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh!  can you make an answer and if such a mechanism exists propose a working solution to my "remember my variables" question?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to use the updated PATH in the interactive shell that you stared `make` from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c makefile with shell commands and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892046/c-makefile-with-shell-commands-and-variables)

Comment: GNU `make` does have a way to cause all the lines of a recipe to be executed in the same shell, but it looks like what you actually want is to set shell variables in one recipe and read them back in a different recipe.  That's never going to work.

Comment: But note also that there is no need to put the `make` variable assignments in a recipe.  Simply put them at top scope, and they will be performed before any recipe is run.

Comment: There is even more weirdness in the small tidbit you've posted, leading me to suspect that you're trying to write your makefile as if it were a script.  It is not, and trying to write it as if it were one will cause you continuing difficulty.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Yea I was completely "off" about the makefile: I did think it were like a script.  I've dumped it as my mechanism to get the bash env required. Instead have a local bash function to run.  It's not share-able; others will have to do their own thing - unless I actually check it in as a distinct script and communicate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make runs each command in a recipe in its own shell (unless declaring `.ONESHELL`). Any modified state such as variables is cleared for each command. And, any variables set are never communicated outside make. For this purpose you're more likely to want to `source` a bash script.

Make are for making files from other files.

---

There are several alternatives to set the variables:

```
# Global scope
VARIABLE := myglobal

# Target specific
mytarget: VARIABLE := targetspecific

# Prefix the command
myprefix:
    VARIABLE=prefix env
```

Comment: Would any of the alternatives work for storing the result of one recipe for use in another? It kinda seems not ?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Only using files.